# How to combine literal array value in my template with an array provided through parameters?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

In my ARM template to deploy a Web Site, I have some "appSettings" that I need to define in the template. I also have a parameter in the template that accepts another array of settings. I would like to combine this incoming array of settings with the ones I literally define in the template itself to produce the final "appSettings" array that I set in my ARM template. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If those are two (or more) arrays that you would like to concatenate, then you can use the `concat(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)` function - see [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#concat). If those are more objects, then you can use `union(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)`.

The full list of ARM functions is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions).

The best way might be to define a [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/variables) which is composed of the concatenation of your different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a similar situation that was solved by using the `union` function. I chose to go with `union` because I had a set of default app settings defined in the ARM template and I also wanted to pass a parameter that would define new settings and possibly override some of the default settings. The `union` function "Returns a single array or object with all elements from the parameters. **Duplicate values or keys are only included once.**" If you use `concat`, settings defined in both the default set and the parameter set will appear multiple times.

```
"variables": {
  "appSettingDefault": [...default values here...],
  "unionAppSettings": "[union(variables('appSettingDefault'), parameters('armAppSettings'))]",
```

Then just assign the variable to the resource property:

```
"siteConfig": {
  "appSettings": "[variables('unionAppSettings')]"
}
```